# Accessing the Key values of objects in an Array Converted from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON string:

```
"Filters": [
   {"IsActive" : "1"},
   {"Gender" : "M"}
]
```

That I'm converting into an array `$filters`. When I `var_dump` I get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["IsActive"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Gender"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
}
```

I am trying to access the Key / Value pairs. The Keys are not always `Gender`, or `IsActive`. They can be anything, with any value.

```
 foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
   echo "\nFilter: " . $key . " => " . $value;
 }
```

But it outputs:

> Filter: Array => Array
>  **Notice**:  Array to string
>   conversion in

**Why am I unable to access the k/v pairs?**

Comment: Why convert it to an array, its a perfectly lovely object in JSON

Comment: I have to convert it to the array.

Comment: Observe: it is an array of arrays

Comment: You're correct. I got coding cross-eyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking deeply enough at the array. Its actually an array of arrays, so one way to process it would beto use another foreach like this

```
foreach ($filters as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "\nFilter: " . $key . " => " . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. The answer was right in front of me the whole time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As this is an array of arrays, you should iterate over each array instead

```
foreach($filters as $index=>$filter) {
     foreach($filter as $key=>$value){
     //...
     }
}
```